# Bad IE11 SVG rendering - background-image

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG image as a background, with `background-size:contain`.
In all browsers except IE, it looks perfect. However, in IE the bottom of the logo is cut off slightly and the edges are blurry. 
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777143/svg-in-img-element-proportions-not-respected-in-ie9/9792254#9792254)(removing set width and height from SVG file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565736/my-background-image-get-cut-off-at-the-bottom)(adding a margin below) and it still cut off, and can't find anything about the blurry edges.

IE11 Rendering:
[image: IE11 Rendering]

Chrome/Firefox Rendering:
[image: Chrome Rendering]
[image: Firefox Rendering]

Here's my CSS for how I'm displaying that image:

```
.header-container::before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 15em;
   padding: 0.825em 0;
   background-image: url('reed-logo-white.svg?1427895453');
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: transparent;
   background-size: contain;
   margin: 1em auto;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, or at least tell me why it's happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code to JSFiddle?

Comment: @ShaunLoftin, what do you mean by "the rest of your code"? What else do you want to see?

Comment: Any solution here? I'm having the same problem. IE11 looks horrible concerning svg-rendering.

Answer (score 3):

I was also frustrated by this problem. The only solution I found was to resave my SVG files so that:
1) the artboard dimensions are pixel integers (no fractions), and
2) if that doesn't work, add 2px to the artboard dimensions (width or height), to add more white space around the artwork