# Background image height being cropped at lower resolution views

Tags: html, css, background-image

Good day to you!
I know that this is a common problem and have been solved many times but really I've tried every search solutions that search engine and stackoverflow returns to me but I really can't fix this one.

The problem is that the background image is cropped when the view is in smaller device.

I have tried setting the html and the body to 100% to no avail.
I have tried setting the background-size to 100% 100% to no avail.
I have tried this link [CSS: Full Size background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059429/css-full-size-background-image) but still to no avail.

Here's the css code:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/bg2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Josefin Sans Regular;
    color: white;

}

html {
    height: 100%;
}


#content {
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,1),
                 0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding-top: 25%;
}
#carHead {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 5em;
}
hr {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0.02)
}
.carousel-item {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

and here's the body of the html code:

```
<body>
<!--head nav-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>
            < logo
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Search">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login 
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<!--end of head nav-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <div id="carHead">
                    <h1>Example of our works</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- featured item carousel -->
        <div id="testcar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#testcar" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#testcar" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#testcar" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/w1.jpg"  height="350px" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Work/Template 1</h5>
                    <p>Use/What for</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/w2.jpg"  height="350px" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Work/Template 2</h5>
                    <p>Use/What for</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/w3.jpg"  height="350px" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Work/Template 3</h5>
                    <p>Use/What for</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testcar" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testcar" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    <!-- end of carousel-->
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="assets/img/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="assets/img/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="assets/img/3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="assets/img/1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

finally the output:

[image]

Comment: min-height: 725px; use something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `min-height` so it will not crop from the bottom of the background image. Check the sample code given below. I have given `min-height:745px` in the body css tag.

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Josefin Sans Regular;
    color: white;
    min-height: 725px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}


#content {
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,1),
                 0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding-top: 25%;
}
#carHead {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 5em;
}
hr {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0.02)
}
.carousel-item {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
<!--head nav-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>
            
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Search">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login 
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<!--end of head nav-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <div id="carHead">
                    <h1>Example of our works</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- featured item carousel -->
        <div id="testcar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#testcar" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#testcar" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#testcar" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg"  height="350px" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Work/Template 1</h5>
                    <p>Use/What for</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg"  height="350px" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Work/Template 2</h5>
                    <p>Use/What for</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg"  height="350px" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Work/Template 3</h5>
                    <p>Use/What for</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testcar" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testcar" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    <!-- end of carousel-->
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-technological-elements-with-transparent-background_1035-7108.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-technological-elements-with-transparent-background_1035-7108.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-technological-elements-with-transparent-background_1035-7108.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-thumbnail"src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-technological-elements-with-transparent-background_1035-7108.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried and it is still cropped. I even tried to run the code snippet and it is cropped there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property ([with growing support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)) to have the image resize in its container. Example below:

```
.banner-image {
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 460px;
}
```

Comment: I tried fiddling around object-fit but it seems like it will work for an image "in a container". On the other hand it will not work if the image is being set as background of the body itself. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It will definitely work. The body is simply a container for the entire height/width of the page. I’d encourage you to take a look at some examples for it. Alternatively, add a absolute positioned div inside the body tag that is 100% width and height with the background as a url to the image. Keep in mind this is poor for screen readers though as you lose metadata.

Comment: Did as you suggested.
Created a div inside the body, absolute positioned, width & height 100% object-fit: contained still the same result.

Comment: @Cedirck can you elaborate on your expected output? As well as updated code of what you’re doing that still isn’t working correctly. I’ve done this many times using either solution. It sounds like you’re trying a combination of both solutions which is incorrect. Your own link to the other SO solution lays out perfectly what your options (and their limitations are). You can't have a background image that covers the entire background AND shows completely on desktop & mobile without being cropped to fit.

Comment: Hmm. I see, I have tried to fixed it on my own by removing the height of the html/body. The problem is that the background image scales with the content so if if content is half the screen of the user's so as the display.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found out for this is removing the 100% set height for both the body and the html. The background displays fine in the mobile view but on tablet devices, the background image will scale on the content inside the body as long as you have a high resolution background image (e.g. 6k x 4K reso).

Comment: It sounds like it's not scaling, fitting, or covering at all and you're merely using a large enough image to fill the body. I would be wary of making clients download a 6k image.